# Wildfly 8.2.0.Final: Misconfiguration because of example datasource or persistence.xml?

Tags: datasource, wildfly, wildfly-8, persistence.xml, persistence-unit

I have three datasources configured in my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="MyPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/myDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="MyPersistenceTestUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="myuser" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="mypass" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="MyLoggingUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="myuser" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="mypass" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

The first is the 'default' unit. It's used by the standard entity manager. The second is needed for running JUnit tests outside of a Java EE environment. The third one is used for logging to be independent from JTA transactions.
This works. But when I start Wildfly, I even get some of these errors (although I don't use H2 in my application):

```
21:32:33,748 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) HHH000319: Could not get database metadata: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "PG_CLASS" not found; SQL statement:
select relname from pg_class where relkind='S' [42102-173]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:331)
```

**It only happens when the application is deployed.**

The idea was to disable or remove the ExampleDS by admin console or in standalone.xml, but when I do that, I get a startup with errors:

```
21:36:20,992 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "com.zonacroft.mycuisine.webserver-TRUNK.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
    "jboss.persistenceunit.\"com.mydomain.myapp.webserver-TRUNK.war#MyLoggingUnit\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]",
    "jboss.persistenceunit.\"com.mydomain.myapp.webserver-TRUNK.war#MyPersistenceTestUnit\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]"
```

What on earth is going on here? Why does this persistence.xml need the exampleDS? Are the `RESOURCE_LOCAL` persistence units maybe wrong configured? (But if so, why do they work then). So what's the problem here?

**[UPDATE]**
I figured out that I don't get startup errors (with exampleDS enabled) when I remove the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` properties from the `RESOURCE_LOCAL` persistence units. But it annoys me that I have to let the exampleDS of Wildfly enabled. Otherwise Wildfly would not start with the application as described above. Why is this so. What's wrong here?

Comment: Can't help with your specific question, but `ExampleDS` is used for the platform default datasource, a new feature introduced in Java EE 7. I'm personally not a fan of using resource local PUs for unit tests. IMHO testing with the real persistence unit (e.g. using Arquillian) allows for more realistic testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only define a datasource for the first persistence unit:

```
<jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/myDS</jta-data-source>
```

That means WildFly uses the default datasource `exampleDS` for your other persistence units.

This causes the exception, since the configured PostgreSQL dialect does not work for the default H2 datasource.

Comment: That's true, but I can't set a non-jta-datasource (since other errors occur then) and I don't need one because the needed parameters are set in the persistence units and it's a local resource. So what's the real solution for this now?

Comment: As I tried to test my logging, it didn't work at all (in JEE environment). But the logging PU works when I use the properties of the JTA datasource with the same datasource but as non-jta-datasource and RESOURCE_LOCAL as transaction type. Here also works 'validate'. I'm not sure if I understand completely why the first definition didn't work, but that's another question.